# Fetch mysql data in bash, function read reads every sentence as variable

Tags: mysql, bash

I trying to get variables from my db, I one value in db I've got 2 words, but command below treat it as 2 variables.

Is there any change to fetch it in my way ?

```
   mysql -uroot -proot --database=symfony -se "SELECT cameras.source, cameras.name, investments.name, users.username FROM cameras JOIN investments ON investments.id = cameras.investment_id JOIN users ON users.id = investments.user_id;" | while read source camera investment username; do
```

mysql result :

```
| source                                                                 | name         | name       | username |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| rtsp://vlc:vlc@test/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0   | camera 1     | investment |  user    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

bash:

```
echo "source :"$source
echo "camera :" :$camera
echo "investments: " $investments
echo "username: " $username
```

result:

```
source :rtsp://vlc:vlc@test/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0channel=1&subtype=0
camera : investment
investments: 1
username:  investment username
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: i just edited post

Comment: this because the space is use ad as  separator

Comment: do i have any solutions ?

Comment: i have post a suggestion  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for avoid the that thge space in camera.name is confused  as a saperator you could replace the space with another char eg `_`

```
 SELECT cameras.source
      , replace(cameras.name, ' ', '_')
      , investments.name, users.username 
  FROM cameras 
  JOIN investments ON investments.id = cameras.investment_id 
  JOIN users ON users.id = investments.user_id;
```